# Geometric sequences interest question

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Winston invests a sum of money at 6% per annum. How many years does it take him to double his money?

I let the initial sum of money be $£a$. Then at the end of the first year, he has $£1.06a$ since he is getting back 6% of his initial deposit. Then at the start of year 2 he has $£(1.06)^2a$ and at the end $£(1.06)^3a$. Then at the start of the nth year he has $£(1.06)^na$

I see that this forms a geometric sequence with a = $£a$ and r = 1.06. Do I find the sum of the first n terms, and see when this is equal to 2a? Or Do I find the term which is equal to 2a?

I find these interest/finance sequence questions very hard to picture/do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a geometric sequence, with the $n$th term equal to

$$a (1.06)^n$$

representing an amount of money in pounds at year $n$.  To find how many years it takes for you to double your money, simply set

$$(1.06)^n = 2 \implies n = \frac{\log{2}}{\log{1.06}}$$

where log can be of any base; I usually choose natural log, otherwise denoted as ln.  I get, as a number, $n \approx 11.86$ years, or $12$ years.